# Mac OS X -> stickies are sometimes scrollable, sometimes not

Tags: macos, mac

I'm on a macbook pro and the stickies app is often acting up.
Sometimes I am able to use the trackpad with two fingers to scroll inside it (on the right side there is still no scrollbar, but it still scrolls) and sometimes I can't.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Scrolling doesn't work for me at all. There are many similar (freeware) replacements for Stickies, maybe have a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

I can replicate this: scrolling works with a wheel mouse but not trackpad for me. It's probably a bug in Stickies. You can report it at http://bugreporter.apple.com

I tried a replacement like [StickEmUp](http://www.jimmcgowan.net/Site/StickEmUp.html), but that appears to be based off the same code, with the same bug.

As a workaround, you can drag-select to cause the text to scroll up and down.

Comment: Good find with the trackpad/scroll mouse behavior.